# Using Ardalis.Specification to query CosmosDb using Linq syntax

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, ardalis-specification

We have a working solution that uses the specification pattern to access CosmosDb using plain text SQL statements.

We are attempting to use the latest version of Ardalis.Specification (5.1.0) to do the same, but using LINQ to provide type safety in our sql.

For a collection `foo` we have a specification:

```cs
using System.Linq;

using Ardalis.Specification;
using Example.Sample.Core.Entities;

namespace Example.Sample.Core.Specifications
{
    public class FooFromIdSpecification : Specification<Foo>
    {
        public FooFromIdSpecification(string id)
        {
            Query.Where(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Where we are having problems is in the base generic repository ... getting the code to generate the sql from specification:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetItemsAsyncEnumerable(ISpecification<T> specification)
{
    # This is the line that is not working
    var foo = (IQueryable<T>)specification.Evaluate(_container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>());

    using var iterator = foo.ToFeedIterator<T>();

    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
        foreach (var item in response)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Hit a wall getting the evaluator to work. Likely missing something obvious.

#### The problem

The code above when called does not hit any try-catch blocks, but `foo` is null.

#### Some sources we have referenced

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-linq-to-sql
- https://github.com/ardalis/Specification
- https://gist.github.com/ShawnShiSS/5ef9be602e62b3aae8b58858386bcf2c
- https://github.com/ShawnShiSS/clean-architecture-azure-cosmos-db

Comment: So..... what is the problem? You need to explain the actual problem. Error messages? Wrong output?

Comment: `it's not working` doesn't help much I know ... this is as much a cry in the dark to see if anyone else has tried this problem. I have my colleague creating a simple basic solution that we will post to GitHub when ready to demonstrate.

Comment: @Ruskin, Have you managed to overcome this? I currently facing the very same issue. Please provide an answer to your question and accept it if you did. 

Comment: Quite some interest in this ... just a heads-up: I never tried integrating with the Entity Framewok CosmosDb implementation. You may get some joy there ... but note, not all linq queries have an equivalent, and you will get some 'not supported' exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We 'got something working' ... not elegant but does the job.

Gotcha - there is no way my colleagues and I discovered of using *SelectMany* using main implementation, which is needed when getting arrays from separate collections e.g. in SQL world:

```sql
select s.foo from c join s in c.someArray
```

This is what worked:

- Created own sub-class off Specification
- Implemented hacky evaluator

```cs
using Ardalis.Specification;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Whatever.Namespace.You.Want
{
    public interface ICosmosDbSpecification<T, TMapped> : ISpecification<T, TMapped>
    {
        Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TMapped>>>? ManySelector { get; }
    }
}
```

Implementing that interface to get the SelectMany functionality down the stack:

```cs
using Ardalis.Specification;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Whatever.Namespace.You.Want
{
    public abstract class CosmosDbSpecification<T, TMapped> : Specification<T, TMapped>, ICosmosDbSpecification<T, TMapped>
    {
        protected new virtual ICosmosDbSpecificationBuilder<T, TMapped> Query { get; }

        public Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TMapped>>>? ManySelector { get; internal set; }

        protected CosmosDbSpecification()
            : this(InMemorySpecificationEvaluator.Default)
        {
        }

        protected CosmosDbSpecification(IInMemorySpecificationEvaluator inMemorySpecificationEvaluator)
            : base(inMemorySpecificationEvaluator)
        {
            this.Query = new CosmosDbSpecificationBuilder<T, TMapped>(this);
        }

    }

    public interface ICosmosDbSpecificationBuilder<T, TResult> : ISpecificationBuilder<T, TResult>
    {
        new CosmosDbSpecification<T, TResult> Specification { get; }
    }

    public class CosmosDbSpecificationBuilder<T, TResult> : SpecificationBuilder<T, TResult>, ICosmosDbSpecificationBuilder<T, TResult>
    {
        public new CosmosDbSpecification<T, TResult> Specification { get; }

        public CosmosDbSpecificationBuilder(CosmosDbSpecification<T, TResult> specification)
            : base(specification)
        {
            this.Specification = specification;
        }
    }


    public static class CosmosDbSpecificationBuilderExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Allows CosmosDb SelectMany methods. WARNING can only have Select OR SelectMany ... using both may throw
        /// </summary>
        public static ICosmosDbSpecificationBuilder<T, TResult> SelectMany<T, TResult>(
            this ICosmosDbSpecificationBuilder<T, TResult> specificationBuilder,
            Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TResult>>> manySelector)
        {
            specificationBuilder.Specification.ManySelector = manySelector;

            return specificationBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

Should probably have changed the `InMemorySpecificationEvaluator.Default` singleton to our own ... but current implementation works and getting on with things.

This then all gets stitched together in repository using bespoke evaluator-like thing:

```cs
using Ardalis.Specification;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Whatever.Namespace.You.Want
{
    public static class SpecificationEvaluator <T>
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<TResult> ApplySpecification<TResult>(Container container, ISpecification<T, TResult> specification)
        {
            var queryable = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(
                true, default, default,
                new CosmosLinqSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase });

            foreach (var criteria in specification.WhereExpressions)
            {
                queryable = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)queryable.Where(criteria);
            }

            if (specification.OrderExpressions != null)
            {
                if (specification.OrderExpressions.Where(x => x.OrderType == OrderTypeEnum.OrderBy ||
                                                            x.OrderType == OrderTypeEnum.OrderByDescending).Count() > 1)
                {
                    throw new DuplicateOrderChainException();
                }

                IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery = null;
                foreach (var orderExpression in specification.OrderExpressions)
                {
                    if (orderExpression.OrderType == OrderTypeEnum.OrderBy)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = Queryable.OrderBy((dynamic)queryable, (dynamic)RemoveConvert(orderExpression.KeySelector));
                    }
                    else if (orderExpression.OrderType == OrderTypeEnum.OrderByDescending)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = Queryable.OrderByDescending((dynamic)queryable, (dynamic)RemoveConvert(orderExpression.KeySelector));
                    }
                    else if (orderExpression.OrderType == OrderTypeEnum.ThenBy)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = Queryable.ThenBy((dynamic)orderedQuery, (dynamic)RemoveConvert(orderExpression.KeySelector));
                    }
                    else if (orderExpression.OrderType == OrderTypeEnum.ThenByDescending)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = Queryable.ThenByDescending((dynamic)orderedQuery, (dynamic)RemoveConvert(orderExpression.KeySelector));
                    }
                }
                if (orderedQuery != null)
                {
                    queryable = orderedQuery;
                }
            }

            if (specification.Skip != null && specification.Skip != 0)
            {
                queryable = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)queryable.Skip(specification.Skip.Value);
            }

            if (specification.Take != null)
            {
                queryable = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)queryable.Take(specification.Take.Value);
            }

            if (typeof(ICosmosDbSpecification<T, TResult>).IsAssignableFrom(specification.GetType()))
            {
                var selectMany = ((ICosmosDbSpecification<T, TResult>)specification).ManySelector;
                if (selectMany != null)
                {
                    if (specification.Selector != null)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Cannot set both Selector and ManySelector on same specification");
                    }

                    if (specification.Take != null || specification.Skip != null)
                    {
                        // until figured out how to implement this on final solution instead of inner root request (gives not supported error in sdk)
                        throw new ApplicationException("Select many does not support take or skip ...");
                    }

                    return (IOrderedQueryable<TResult>)queryable.SelectMany(selectMany);
                }
            }

            return (IOrderedQueryable<TResult>)queryable.Select(specification.Selector);
        }

        private static LambdaExpression RemoveConvert(LambdaExpression source)
        {
            var body = source.Body;
            while (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
                body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;

            return Expression.Lambda(body, source.Parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

and use as so in your generic base repository:

```cs
IOrderedQueryable<TResult> queryable = 
    SpecificationEvaluator<T>.ApplySpecification(_container, specification);

using var iterator = queryable.ToFeedIterator<TResult>();
...
```

With a specification something like:

```cs
public class GetDetailSpecification : CosmosDbSpecification<TypeOfData, TypeOfOutput>
    {
public GetFooBarSpecification(YourParameterisedFilterObject filter)
        {
            if (filter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));
            Query.Select(x => new TypeOfOutput { Foo = x.Bar });
            Query.Where(x => x.Id == filter.Id && x.PartitionKey == filter.PartitionKeyValue);
        }
}
```

Comment: Robert let me know if you get a more elegant solution ... good luck